# border effekt like in Windows 10 with css3 / html5

Tags: javascript, html, css, border, effect

I would like to create this effect in html5. Does anyone have an idea if and how this is possible?

[border effect on mouse nearby](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Kakb.gif)

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.onmousemove = function(event) {
    var x = event.clientX - 100, y = event.clientY - 100;
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = "light";
    div.style.cssText += "left: " + x + "px; top: " + y + "px;";
    if (document.getElementById("light")) {
        document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById("light"));
    }
    document.body.appendChild(div);
};
```

```css
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    background: lightgray;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

table {
    background: #505050;   
}

#light {
    background: radial-gradient(white, #111111); 
    z-index: 1; 
    width: 200px; 
    height: 200px; 
    border-radius: 50%; 
    position: fixed; 
}
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Box 1</td>
<td>Box 2</td>
<td>Box 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Box 4</td>
<td>Box 5</td>
<td>Box 6</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

This can make the illusion that it is lighting up. However, I cannot find a way to make it not show on the document, just the table. Hope this helps a bit